# ReactJS Google Maps with Multiple Markers using Geocoder

Tags: arrays, mongodb, google-maps, reactjs, google-geocoder

I am trying to figure out how to get geocoder "data" to google maps api in an array.

array from data base -> geocoder (geocoder turns array to individual objects) -> objects back to array -> array looped to Google Map

From the database to the geocoder everything is good (data is being passed as an array with multiple objects that are holding each city name) but once data is passed through the geecoder it separates the array passing each object individually. Im assuming at this point I need to push each object into an array again before I loop through them and pass the lat and long to the map.
Right now how the code is it makes a marker with a new map for each location.

```
 import React from 'react';
 import geocoder from 'google-geocoder';
 import FeedMap from './feedMap.js';
 import { GoogleMap, Marker } from 'react-google-maps';
 import MapLoader from './maploader.js';
 import { default as MarkerClusterer } from "react-google-maps/lib/addons/MarkerClusterer";


var Location = React.createClass({
 getInitialState: function(){
  return {
   petTrip: []
   }
   },

    getAllpetTripFromServer: function(){
     var self = this;
     $.ajax({
     method: 'GET',
     url: '/travel'
     }).done(function(data){
     console.log(data, "I am the data from line 17");
     self.setState({ petTrip: data })
     })
   },

   componentDidMount: function(){
    this.getAllpetTripFromServer();
     },

     render: function(){
      return (
      <div>
        <AllpetTrip petTrip={this.state.petTrip}/>
      </div>
     )
    }

   });

  var AllpetTrip = React.createClass({
   render: function(){
    var trips = this.props.petTrip.map(function(item){
    return <Geolocator start={item.startPoint}/>
    });
   return (
    <div>
    { trips }
    </div>
   )
  }
 });

 var Geolocator = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
     location: undefined
    }
    },

   getLocations: function(){
   var locationArr = [];
   var self = this;
   var key = { key: 'AIzaSyC9Zst0uBpxGJ2P4LLv3IMATpN9Ppl4ImI'};
   var coder = geocoder(key);
   var geo = coder.find(this.props.start, function(err, data){
    self.setState({ location: data });
    return data;

    })
    },

   componentDidMount: function(){
   this.getLocations();
   },


   render: function(){

    var startPoints = this.state.geolocations ?  this.state.geolocations.map(function(item){
     return <Marker position={ { lat: item.location.lat, lng:  item.location.lng} } icon={'img/marker.png'}/>
       }) : null;

    return(
    <div id="google-map">
      <MapLoader>
      <GoogleMap
       defaultZoom={4}
       center={{lat: 40., lng: -99.000}}>


      >
        <MarkerClusterer
        averageCenter
        enableRetinaIcons
        gridSize={20}
        >
        { startPoints }
        </MarkerClusterer>
      </GoogleMap>
      </MapLoader>
      </div>

     )
    }

   });

    module.exports = Location;
```

Comment: What data are you sending to the API (street address?) and what data are you requesting? Is the lat/lon simply for your markers?

Comment: I am taking an array of City Names passing them to the geocoder for the lat and lngs (I have that much working). After the geocoder I no longer have an array but individual GeoData objects for each City. I want to pass the lat and lng from each object to my Google Map for multiple Markers.